# Getting started with backbonejs - what should a server return

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am totally new to Backbone.js library and read through the whole documentation and understood the working of the library. In the below cases what should the response from the server be for proper working of application designed using backbone (without putting a extra stroke/code).

assume a model like below

```
window.person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: "",
        email: "dummy@gmail.com"
    },
    urlRoot: "PersonApp"
});
```

1. What JSON should server return assuming **validation went well** for `model.save()`
2. What JSON should server return for `model.fetch()`
3. What JSON should server return for `model.destroy()`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have a look in the [Backbone.Sync documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync), it says that you should respond to requests with the attributes that have changed on the server.

So to answer your questions:

1. The JSON request for `model.save` should return the attributes that have changed as part of the save.  In the case of a create this would be the whole model; in the case of update just the fields that have changed.  (Or if you're lazy and don't mind updating the entire client side model, you could just return the whole model).

   So an acceptable response would be `{ 'name' : 'a name', 'email' : 'an@email.com' }`
2. Fetch should just return the model in JSON form.  So, the same example I used for `model.save` would work.
3. I'm not entirely sure, but I don't think Backbone validates the returned data from delete requests so you should be able to return anything, so long as it's not an HTTP error.  According to @a.real.human.being below, an empty response also causes errors.  So returning a 200 with "OK" in the body (or similar) seems like a reasonable plan.

Comment: JSON response from `destroy` doesn't matter. Backbone listens for a 20X response for success.

Comment: @abraham Yeah i knew, backbone relies on HTTP status 200 for OK so anything that returns HTTP Status meant the request succeeded for backbone

Comment: @abraham This is not the case. If you send no JSON response on a `destroy`, an `error` is generated on the model. However, if you send anything at all (even `json_encode("happy birthday")`), then it treats it as a success.

Comment: For model.save(), when creating a new entry on the server: Is it OK to only return the "_id" of the created entry from the server instead of the whole model? The rest of the model should exist in Backbone anyways already.