# Backbone.js model.save() - proper server response

Tags: backbone.js

Something seems to be wrong, either my server response or my save function.
In neither case success nor error function of model.save() gets invoked.

My server response:

```
exports.updateBusinessBannerAd = function(req, res) {
// update banner ad
db.insert(req.body, req.body._id, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Update business banner ad: ' + err.message + '   ' + err['status-code']);
        res.send(err['status-code'], { header: 'Update banner ad', message: err.message, type: 'error'});
    }
    else {
        res.send(200);
    }
});
```

};

And here my client code:

```
saveBannerAd: function(self) {
        self.model.id = self.model.attributes._id; 
        self.model.save({
            success: function(model, res) {
                    utils.growl( 'Banner Ad', 'has been updated!', 'info');
                    self.resetHandler();
            },
            error: function(model, res) {
                console.log(res);
                utils.growl(res.header, res.message, res.type);
                return;
            }    
        }); 
    },
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I had same question when i was Backbone.js noob. Here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706260/getting-started-with-backbonejs-what-should-a-server-return

Answer (score 1):

Okay, adding { id: self.model.get('id') } as first argument to model.save() fixed my issue.

[In this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757555/how-do-i-trigger-the-success-callback-on-a-model-save?rq=1)

someone suggested setting 'null' as first argument serves as placeholder, but my experience is that this will invoke the error function.