# Backbone + Express: PUT and DELETE requests fail

Tags: rest, backbone.js, express

My Backbone application has a button that destroys a `Backbone.Model`.
I tried explicitly firing a `DELETE` via Postman, but it tells me it can't `DELETE /stuff/0`.

I can successfully `GET` and `POST`, but not `PUT` or `DELETE`.

Here's my server code for `DELETE`:

```
var app = express();
...
app.delete('/stuff:id', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    var thing = mystuff[id];
    mystuff = mystuff.splice(id, 1);

    res.send('deleted ' + thing);
});
```

My `PUT` and `DELETE` functions aren't even entered.

And by the way, this isn't a form, so I don't believe I need `methodOverride`.

What's going on? Is this an issue with my server code or with my application?

Comment: Have you tried rendering the ID of the deleted model? `res.send(req.params.id);`

Comment: The `console.log` statements that I have in my functions aren't executed, so they're not even entered (PUT and DELETE). I did just try what you said to make sure, and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your route:

```
app.delete('/stuff:id', function(req, res)
```

Should be:

```
app.delete('/stuff/:id', function(req, res)
```

If I'm not mistaking, Backbone also wants you to render the Id of the deleted model when the deletion is complete.

```
res.send(req.params.id);
```

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706260/getting-started-with-backbonejs-what-should-a-server-return), the server response from a DELETE is not validated by Backbone, so I can return anything, and in fact must return something or Backbone treats it as an error (supposedly).